# TypeError: argument of type 'Item' is not iterable

Tags: python

So I've created an object 'Item' which contains a list within a list

```
        for item in stock_list:
            item_list = item.split(",")
            self.__items += [Item(item_list[0], item_list[1], float(item_list[2]), int(item_list[3]))]
```

When trying to find the item which matches the code (index 0) I am trying to create a new function to return this item

```
def find_item(self, code):
    for item in self.__items:
        if code in item:
            print(item)
```

When I run this it gives me the `TypeError: argument of type 'Item' is not iterable` error and I can't figure out why?
Should I create a `getCode()` function which returns the private self.__code? Or would that not make a difference?

Comment: What is code, what is its type? What are you trying to match?

Comment: you probably must add a method `__iter__()` in your Item class

Comment: @Shari `self.__items` is not what you think it is, most likely. It probably is just a single `Item`, not a list thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue occurs in line -

```
if code in item:
```

For custom classes, you cannot do - `x in C` - where C is an object (instance) of a custom class, unless the custom class has a [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method . Example -

```
>>> class CC:
...     pass
...
>>> class CB:
...     def __contains__(self, item):
...             if item == 1:
...                     return True
...             else:
...                     return False
...
>>> cco = CC()
>>> cbo = CB()
>>> 1 in cco
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'CC' is not iterable
>>> 1 in cbo
True
>>> 2 in cbo
False
```

---

But given this, `__contains__()` is basically used for membership test where an object can contain multiple elements (take list/dict as examples),

If you are trying to compare code is equal to some other variable like `self.__code` . Then you would either need to provide some kind of method (or property) that returns `__code` , if `__code` is again some kind of list or such, and you are trying to check if `item` is in `self.__code` , you can override the `__contains__()` as shown above.